# AWS SAM Deployment: Failed to create managed resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, sam

When I try to deploy the hello world SAM application using `sam deploy --guided`, I get the following error.

```
Configuring SAM deploy
======================

        Looking for config file [samconfig.toml] :  Not found

        Setting default arguments for 'sam deploy'
        =========================================
        Stack Name [sam-app]: sam-app
        AWS Region [eu-west-1]: eu-west-1
        #Shows you resources changes to be deployed and require a 'Y' to initiate deploy
        Confirm changes before deploy [y/N]: y
        #SAM needs permission to be able to create roles to connect to the resources in your template
        Allow SAM CLI IAM role creation [Y/n]: y
        #Preserves the state of previously provisioned resources when an operation fails
        Disable rollback [y/N]: y
        HelloWorldFunction may not have authorization defined, Is this okay? [y/N]: y
        Save arguments to configuration file [Y/n]: y
        SAM configuration file [samconfig.toml]: 
        SAM configuration environment [default]: 

        Looking for resources needed for deployment:
        Creating the required resources...
Error: Failed to create managed resources: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: User: arn:aws:iam::899719
272550:user/xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:CreateChangeSet on resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:899719272550:stack/aws-sam-cli-managed-default/* because no identity-based policy allows the cloudformation:CreateChangeSet action
```

Could you please help me to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never. The answer to your problem is in your question itself.

`SAM cli` uses your **AWS Credentials/Role** that you had setup while configuring your `aws cli` using `aws configure` command. If you don't know what I'm talking about check [Setting up AWS credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started-set-up-credentials.html) here.

Needless to say this role needs to have atleast the following set of permission for it to create/update cloudformation stacks successfully.

- `cloudformation:CreateChangeSet`
- `cloudformation:CreateStack`
- `cloudformation:DeleteStack`
- `cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet`
- `cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents`
- `cloudformation:DescribeStacks`
- `cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet`
- `cloudformation:GetTemplateSummary`
- `cloudformation:ListStackResources`
- `cloudformation:UpdateStack`

The role you are using is currently missing the `cloudformation:CreateChangeSet` permission and hence it's failing. Try adding all of the permissions mentioned above to your role and re-deploy the app.

##### Reference:

- [AWS Serverless Application Model - Permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-permissions.html)

Answer (score 0):

The role permission you need is `AWSCloudFormationFullAccess`

and if you can not grant full access then you can try with `AWSCloudFormationReadOnlyAccess`